# How to filter/search columns in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have followed this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) on how to create/filter search a table. But I want to filter search for each column in my own table. **Currently, it only searches for the First Name column**. How can I do this?

**This is the code:**

**myHTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th> First Name </th>
        <th> Last Name </th> 
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Language </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Kole</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pearl</td>
        <td>Shine</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>Hindi</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Pool</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Arabic</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>David</td>
        <td>Struff</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>German</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    }
                else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
</script>
```

How can I filter all columns for searching? Currently, it searches the First Name column only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check each nodes of the table row instead of just checking `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]`. The zeroth node corresponds to first name field, that's why the search result restricts to the first name field only.. Search for all the nodes instead.

Leave the `tr` node with class name of `header` while making the row hidden.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        isFound = false;
        for(j=0; j< alltags.length; j++) {
          td = alltags[j];
          if (td) {
              txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
              if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  tr[i].style.display = "";
                  j = alltags.length;
                  isFound = true;
              }
            }       
          }
          if(!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th> First Name </th>
        <th> Last Name </th> 
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Language </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Kole</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>English</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pearl</td>
        <td>Shine</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>Hindi</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Pool</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Arabic</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>David</td>
        <td>Struff</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>German</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Beautiful! just what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

gets the first `td` which is the content for the first column in the table meaning the FirstName column.
Do a loop on all `td` tags instead of getting only the first one and you'll get the functionality you need.

Comment: I removed the [0] index but I am not able to filter now. Even the First name column is not working.

Comment: I did not say remove the [0] index. I said do a for loop on all tds for each row.

Comment: Which is basically exact same thing `Nitheesh` said a few minutes after I did. But he gave you the code to copy and paste. And I think doing so in the state you are in, is harmfull and will cause you to learn absolutelly nothing.
As long as you don't try yourself, you won't learn ANYTHING. Just a friendly advice.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate you trying to help me learn. I have a quick requirement for a mini-project, and Javascript is a language that is new to me. I will learn it soon. Still, thank you so much for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Get all table rows. Loop through these rows. Put all the `innerText` from the `<td>s` in each row together into a *string*. Check the first occurrence of the search value in the string. If the value is not found, hide the row with `display: none` else show the row with `display: table-row`.

### Example

```js
const id = "myTable";
const selector = `#${id} tr:not(.header)`;
// Get all rows
const trs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

function myFunction(event) {
  let search = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

  trs.forEach((tr) => {
    // Get all cells in a row
    let tds = tr.querySelectorAll("td");

    // String that contains all td textContent from a row
    let str = Array.from(tds).map((td) => {
      return td.textContent.toLowerCase();
    }).join("");

    tr.style.display = (str.indexOf(search) > -1) ? "table-row" : "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th> First Name </th>
    <th> Last Name </th>
    <th> Age </th>
    <th> Language </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Kole</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>English</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pearl</td>
    <td>Shine</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Hindi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Pool</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Arabic</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Struff</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>German</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```